# Zombie session for websocket (NODEJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

How can I check for zombie session in websocket connection in nodejs?
I have created a chatting server and I wanted to check if the client is still connected to server. When a clients disconnects manually it sends a 'close' signal which is easy to check but in case when there is a network problem and client is unable to send message there is nothing I can check for.
So I wanted something like zombie session to check whether the client is connected or not? I am doing this on nodejs server using websocket..

Comment: I don't know what a zombie session is, but you could simply ping each client every second or so.

Comment: Exactly I also don't know about zombie session thats why I asked here but I am sure it is related with my problem here.
I also don't how can I ping each client in websocket on nodejs...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create zombie/defunct process in nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863302/how-do-you-create-zombie-defunct-process-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

Well Zombie Sessions are mostly created when any user is connected to websoket but his Internet connection lost before disconnecting, in this case he is assumed as a active client by the server but actually he is not , for this zombie session you can check within a time interval for active users by sending a ping and receiving a pong for that , the ping pong model.