# How do you create zombie/defunct process in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, zombie-process

There are many posts here (e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217507/zombies-in-bash) that shows how to create zombie processes in bash or c.  I would like to know if there is a way to create them in nodejs so when I do `ps ax | grep node`, there's a line whose command section is `node <defunct>`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have a script that reports if there are defunct node processes running on a system.  I want to test it by creating some defunct processes.

Comment: So why do you need to create zombies with node.js? Why don't you just use bash?

Comment: The script reports if there are defunct NODE processes running.

Comment: You could either create a bash script named `node` or, during the testing, change the condition that looks for `node` named processes to anything else.

Comment: try `fg` and then it will bring up any backgroup zombie process. `ctrl + c` will kill it from there

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own questions in case it helps anyone. Turns out to be pretty easy to do it in node. After you run the following script, you can do a `ps ax | grep node` and you should see an entry with `[node] <defunct>`.

```
var cp = require('child_process');

if(process.send){ //this is a child process
    process.exit();
}

//main process, so spawn a child process
cp.fork(__filename);

//this keeps the main process busy and unable to respond to child's exit, making child defunct
while(true){};
```